# Pandas to_datetime casting issue

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Certain odd things are casted by pandas to dates instead of `NaT`. For example `pd.to_datetime(['1M'])` or `pd.to_datetime(['Monday'])` returns dates instead of `NaT` or an array of objects. is there a way to control for this? or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the behaviour of `to_datetime`, for instance if you passed just a time, it will generate a default date component of today. I don't think you can control this, your best bet would to filter these values or just replace them manually

Comment: The other possibility, which will be slow, is to define a function that tries to create a `datetime` object for each value and when it throws an error catch it and return NaT or object or whatever you desire

Comment: If your date strings are of a common format e.g. year-month-day, you could try `pd.to_datetime(['1M'], format='%Y%m%d, coerce=True)` - dates not able to be parsed will be replace with `NaT`.

Comment: I want to allow for arbitrary data and check if it is a date. So example, ordinal data like `['Monday', 'Tuesday']` without having it casted :(

Comment: if there wasnt an underscore, that would be mildly amusing